# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(), in image classification problem

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I doing image classification using predefined model vgg16, I got 89% accuracy in validation data, To increase the model accuracy, I did an image augmentation, but got some errors. please help me on how to fit for the model.
here my code.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

train_datagen.fit(X_train)
```

I am using the input image are 64x64x3. 
I am a fit model like this.

```
history = model.fit_generator(
      train_datagen.flow(X_train,y_train),
      steps_per_epoch=(X_train)/32 ,
      epochs=30,
      validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
      validation_steps=(X_test)/32,
verbose=1)

Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-ff3a9aaa40da> in <module>()
      5       validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
      6       validation_steps=(X_test)/32,
----> 7 verbose=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1416             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1417             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1418             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1419 
   1420     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    178             steps_done = 0
    179             batch_index = 0
--> 180             while steps_done < steps_per_epoch:
    181                 generator_output = next(output_generator)
    182 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to @jmetz, @suri you have the same issue with your `validation_steps` parameter, as you initialized it to `(X_test)/32`(probably not a scalar).
Check your `validation_steps.shape` / `len(validation_steps)` and your `steps_per_epoch.shape` / `len(steps_per_epoch)`(depending on the input dimensions).
They have to be scalars.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `steps_per_epoch` should be a scalar (single value).

You set it to `(X_train)/32`.

Comment: hi jmetz , I mean its to apply autoencoder to the data.

Comment: hi @suri - regardless, the error from within `keras` implies that `steps_per_epoch` should be a single value and you pass in an array, so that's the cause of the problem.